# Spotify + AppleScript: Add current track to playlist

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

I've found some scripts how to control Spotify through AppleScript. But they only include things like play/pause, next, previous, stop. I was searching for some references on Spotify for AppleScript, but I didn't find any.

Is it possible to add the current playing track in Spotify to a specific playlist with AppleScript, and then, assign a system wide shortcut for that script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Every single scriptable app is inherently documented. In AppleScript Editor, choose Open Dictionary… from the File menu and choose the app.

2) No, you can't modify playlists using Spotify's scripting interface.

Comment: what about adding to the play queue? Or should I keep on dreaming with that..?

Comment: Everything that's possible is there in the documentation. That doesn't include play queue manipulation.

Answer (score 10):

This actually is possible, provided you have an Internet connection.

Although the [Spotify AppleScript API](https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/) doesn't natively support adding songs to a playlist, you can call their [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) (which does support this feature) from your script.

It would look something like this:

```
do shell script "curl -i -X POST 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{USER_NAME}/playlists/" & playlist_id & "/tracks?uris=" & track_id & "' -H 'Authorization: Bearer " & oauth_id & "' -H 'Accept: application/json'"
```

where

1. `playlist_id` is the ID from the URL for your playlist (whether it is public or private) in the format `https://open.spotify.com/user/{USER_NAME}/playlist/playlist_id`
2. `track_id` is the Spotify URI for a song (which you can get using the AppleScript API: `set track_id to id of the current track`, for example)
3. `oauth_id` is the authorization key you get from OAuth when you register and authorize your application (this is the tricky one); also remember to request private playlist modification scope when you authorize if you want to be able to use this with private playlists

As for the universal shortcut, I created a systemwide [service](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-automator-services--cms-20782) in Automator that simply ran my AppleScript and assigned it to a shortcut [in System Preferences](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18418?locale=en_US).

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution, I haven't thought about using their web api. thanks!

Comment: @23tux Glad I could help! I was trying to do the same thing you were when I stumbled upon this question, so hopefully someone will find it useful.

Comment: Take a look here http://node-machine.org/machinepack-spotify. It will help you to get a URL for Oauth token. As for a **responseType** parameter don't forget to specify it as **token**.